# how to invoke a method for every second in ruby

Tags: ruby, rhodes, stopwatch

I wanted to create a stopwatch program in ruby so I googled it and found this [**SO Q**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858970/how-to-get-a-stopwatch-program-running).

But over there, the author calls the `tick` function with `1000xxx.times`. I wanted to know how I can do it using something like `(every second).times` or for each increment of second do call the `tick` function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: In Ruby there is something like `succ` in Time class. `t = Time.now       #=> 2007-11-19 08:23:57 -0600
t.succ             #=> 2007-11-19 08:23:58 -0600` This shows the next second of time. And I want to do it recursively.

Comment: I want to show the time on screen for each increment of the seconds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Thread.new do
  while true do
    puts Time.now # or call tick function
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I also need to show the elapsed time finally and I should record the time somewhere so that it will be useful to resume the operation if the stopwatch is halted.

Comment: may be before doing puts `Time.now` I should store it in some var `t` and then `puts` that `t` would do.. Am I right? :-/

Comment: You are right. Also, if you are developing clock application, you might want to use lower sleep value (0.1 e.g.), store time from previous run in variable and output new value only if it's greater than previous (modulo second) otherwise your clock will be "jumpy" sometimes.

Comment: I dont like the answer, as you inevitably will loose time; e.g. after 1M loops far more than 1M seconds will be spent.

Comment: Technically, any other callback/timeout system will use thread with sleeps inside. Note that sleep doesn't consume cpu cycles while sleeping.

Comment: Yepp, was more worrying about the non-sleep code execution time. What about integrating some sync-with-realtime functionality? Of course that will add code to the loop and increase the loop-delay; I guess it all depends how much time is lost during "call tick function" and how long the ticker is intended to run :-)

Answer (score 17):

This function:

```
def every_so_many_seconds(seconds)
  last_tick = Time.now
  loop do
    sleep 0.1
    if Time.now - last_tick >= seconds
      last_tick += seconds
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

When used like this:

```
every_so_many_seconds(1) do
  p Time.now
end
```

Results in this:

```
# => 2012-09-20 16:43:35 -0700
# => 2012-09-20 16:43:36 -0700
# => 2012-09-20 16:43:37 -0700
```

The trick is to sleep for less than a second.  That helps to keep you from losing ticks.  Note that you cannot guarantee you'll never lose a tick.  That's because the operating system cannot guarantee that your unprivileged program gets processor time when it wants it.

Therefore, make sure your clock code does not depend on the block getting called every second.  For example, this would be bad:

```
every_so_many_seconds(1) do
  @time += 1
  display_time(@time)
end
```

This would be fine:

```
every_so_many_seconds(1) do
  display_time(Time.now)
end
```

Comment: if I use `every_so_many_seconds(1) do
  p Time.now
end
` it displays each second multiple times Why is it so? Can you explain?

Comment: @clone, I introduced that bug during an edit (and like a fool, I didn't test it).  It's fixed now.

Comment: Why not `last_tick += seconds` instead of `last_tick = Time.now`? It would be more accurate.

Comment: @cbliard That sounds reasonable, but I don't see any change in how the code acts when I tried that change.  BTW, I did just now notice that however last_tick is set, it should be set before the yield; I've edited the answer accordingly.  This helps to prevent lost ticks if the block takes significant time.

Comment: @WayneConrad The loop time is not exactly 100ms but 100ms + extra computing time. Each time the loop evaluates, the rounding error adds to itself and the time slowly drifts. When running this function to display `tick` every second on my machine, I had a 1-second difference after 10 minutes. 599 `tick` were displayed. There should have been 600. For a short-living process, this is perfectly fine but for a long-living server process it can be an issue. By doing `last_tick += seconds`, you ensure that the maximum drift will be the `sleep` time: 100ms.

Comment: @cbliard Ah, I understand.  Thanks for explaining it so well, and for suggesting the improvement.  I'll fold it into the answer in a moment.