# Ruby countdown timer

Tags: ruby

I found a countdown timer on this site which works well in linux, but I need this exact thing done in Ruby. I am new to ruby so having trouble figuring this out.

```
  ==Linux version==

   seconds=20; date1=$((`date +%s` + $seconds)); 
   while [ "$date1" -ne `date +%s` ]; do 
   echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$(($date1 - `date +%s` )) +%H:%M:%S)\r"; 
   done
```

So far I have tried this which does not give me the desired output

```
   t = Time.now
    seconds = 30
    date1 = (t + seconds)
    while t != date1
      puts t 
      sleep 1
    end
```

This gives an output like this which A) is not counting down and B) has date added which I don't want.

```
  2015-05-28 09:57:18 -0500
  2015-05-28 09:57:18 -0500
  2015-05-28 09:57:18 -0500
  2015-05-28 09:57:18 -0500
```

I want it to output like the linux version which looks like this

```
  00:00:30
  00:00:29
  00:00:28
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is causing it to fail - please give some code examples and/or error messages so we can see the trouble you're having.

Comment: All the solutions below will not print _exactly_ once a second, but every one second plus the time it takes to run the code inside the loop. If you're running this for a long time, it might be off quite a bit. The solutions might work fine for you though, you have to decide that depending on your use case. For a solution that counteracts this effect see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12522514/192702

Comment: @PatrickOscity, that's a nice solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, if you just need the output and don't use any Time related info :

```
30.downto(0) do |i|
  puts "00:00:#{'%02d' % i}"
  sleep 1
end
```

With time (1st draft) :

```
t = Time.new(0)
countdown_time_in_seconds = 300 # change this value

countdown_time_in_seconds.downto(0) do |seconds|
  puts (t + seconds).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks this works also and it doesn't have the 18 in the time.

Comment: But what if I want it to count down more than 60 seconds say 5 minutes or 300 seconds?

Comment: In that case, it's really easier to go for some date formatting. Gonna edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks everyone these are all great answers. @floum your answer also worked. I cannot select all answers so going to select yours to close this topic out.

Comment: note that for 30 seconds, it is probably no big deal.  if it is to count down 2 hours or 1.5 days, then this will be counting that many seconds plus any processing time between the sleep call... so the final sleeping time will be more than what is specified. @dax 's answer won't have that issue, as it is using a time now and end time to compare

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def countdown(seconds)
  date1 = Time.now + seconds
  while Time.now < date1
    t = Time.at(date1.to_i - Time.now.to_i)
    p t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    sleep 1
  end
end
```

This is tacking an extra hour to the time...not sure why that is, but the big thing is to use `Time.now` the whole way through.

*edit* if you don't want to use it as a method, you can just use the code inside:

```
date1 = Time.now + 5 # your time here
while Time.now < date1
  t = Time.at(date1.to_i - Time.now.to_i)
  p t.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: it's a method, so you need to call `countdown x` where `x` is what you want to countdown from

Comment: yeah sorry, I forgot to call the method doh! It is working now. Thank you!!

Comment: Only one thing... why does it format the time as  "18:00:30" instead of 00:00:30..00:00:29...?

Comment: funny it was formatting it as "01:00:30" for me...maybe something with time zones?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you do this so that it prints the output on the same line overwriting the last output?  I have been playing around using \r & "$stdout.flush" but haven't had much luck. it keeps putting each countdown on a separate line. It would be nice to have this output on just one line.

Comment: on the command line?  I don't think that's possible..I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the first method dax mentioned but removing the %H which allowed me to call it using longer times

```
def countdown(seconds)
  date1 = Time.now + seconds
  while Time.now < date1
    t = Time.at(date1.to_i - Time.now.to_i)
    puts t.strftime('%M:%S')
    sleep 1
  end 
end
```

Comment: and nobody upvoted @dax's answer until 5 years later by me